# JNI: How to convert a group of data from c++ to Java

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to send some data from c++ to java using JNI.

In c++ I have:

```
Array[0]:
string name = "myName"
int iterations = 16
float value = 15
... etc
```

So I want to use JNI to return all data on Java, I'm trying this, but don't work

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_testing_data_MainActivity_getDATA(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
// 1º Create a temp object
jobject dataClass
    {
        jstring name;
                jint iterations;
                jfloat value;
    };
```

`jobject tempObject = env->NewObject();

// Get data in c++ format int temp object type
std::vector<dataClass > data = getDataClass();  // First error, must be a c++ class, how could i get it?

// How much memory i need?
int dataSize = data.size();

// Reserve memory in java format
jint tempValues[dataSize];
jobjectArray tempArray = env->NewObjectArray(dataSize,dataClass,0); // 2º Error, it doesn 't create the class

    // Temporal store data in jarray
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize ; i++)
{
    tempArray[i].name = data[i].name;
            tempArray[i].iterations = data[i].iterations;
            tempArray[i].value = data[i].value;
}

return tempArray;   // return temp array`

}

Are correct this steps to return a structure/object with data? How is possible to fix the errors?

Comment: The 2nd argument to NewObjectArray, had to be a java class reference, and you get by doing env->FindClass("fullpackagelevelnameofyourjavalclass");

Comment: Try serializing data, or json string

Comment: You cannot define a Java class like that in C. What you should look into is a class in Java like:
`class MyData { String name; int iterations; float value; MyData(String name, int iterations, float value) { this.name = name; this.iterations = iterations; this.value = value; } }`

Comment: Then you can instantiate the class with your information for populating your Java array via [NewObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4517). You can set the `jobjectArray` elements from your  constructed `jobject`s via [SetObjectArrayElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp21699).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting everything to JNI types is not a good idea. Generally, it is better to create a peer object, i.e. a handle pointer to the native resource - like the hWnd in the Windows GUI Programming.

Comment: You're welcome. Just be careful the pointer type may different between 32bit and 64bit os.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string to store all data as a sequence data. Field are separated by a separator (":" for example), like this:

```
std::string sequenceData = "my name" + ":" + "16" + ":" + "15" + ...;
```

Pass this sequence to java then split it to get desired value. Use `String.split()` or `StringTokenizer`.